# Find all documents that share max(value) found in aggregate step

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find all documents that *share* the max(num_sold).  I cant just sort descending and do a limit(1) because I'd miss the case where other docs also have the same max(num_sold).  Given this over-simplified dataset:

```
{"item":"Apple", "num_sold": 49}
{"item":"Orange", "num_sold": 55}
{"item":"Peach", "num_sold": 55}
{"item":"Grape", "num_sold": 20}
{"item":"Banana", "num_sold": 20}
```

I want to get back

```
{"item":"Orange", "num_sold": 55}
{"item":"Peach", "num_sold": 55}
```

Using SQL, this is a simple query and then join back to the main dataset. I'm a bit stumped on how to do this in MongoDB.

I've found the max, but how do I get all docs that have that max?

```
db.t.aggregate(
    {$group:{
          _id:null,
          num_sold:{$max:"$num_sold"}
          }
    }
);
{ "_id" : null, "num_sold" : 55 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by grouping on `num_sold` and then using `$sort` and `$limit` pipeline stages to get just the docs with the maximum value:

```js
db.t.aggregate([
    // Group by num_sold, assembling an array of docs with each distinct value.
    {$group: {
        _id: '$num_sold',
        docs: {$push: '$$ROOT'}
    }},
    // Sort the groups by _id descending to put the max num_sold group first.
    {$sort: {_id: -1}},
    // Return just the first (max num_sold) group of docs.
    {$limit: 1}
])
```

Output:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : 55.0, 
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5726a62879ce3350ff8d607e"), 
            "item" : "Orange", 
            "num_sold" : 55.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5726a62879ce3350ff8d607f"), 
            "item" : "Peach", 
            "num_sold" : 55.0
        }
    ]
}
```